# How to run eb init specifying node.js version 8?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I run `eb init` and deploy, I get the node.js version 6, how can I specify that I want node.js version 8 when executing `eb init` command?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an interesting question and I would love to know if there's an easier way, but here's how I got it working:

1. Determine the latest `SolutionStack` name as listed [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/concepts.platforms.html#w273aac13c13c43b9). Presently, this is "64bit Amazon Linux 2017.09 v4.4.4 running Node.js".
2. Perform `eb init -p "64bit Amazon Linux 2017.09 v4.4.4 running Node.js"`
3. create a `.ebextensions` directory.
4. create a file `.ebextensions/nodejs_version.config`
5. add the following snippet to it:

   ```
   option_settings:
     aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:nodejs:
       NodeVersion: 8.9.3
   ```
6. `eb create`
7. Once the environment has begun building, you can execute:

   ```
   aws elasticbeanstalk describe-configuration-settings \
     --environment-name <environment-name> \
     --application-name <application-name>
   ```

Look for option settings in the `aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:nodejs` namespace and you should see the `NodeVersion` assigned to 8.9.3.

Ideally, "64bit Amazon Linux 2017.09 v4.4.4 running Node.js" itself should identify the latest version; you shouldn't need to add an option setting for this, unfortunately that is not so.

Answer (score 0):

Please check below link for supported version of node.js:

[Elastic Beanstalk supported platforms](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/platforms/platforms-supported.html#platforms-supported.nodejs)

Then you can use below command with your specified version:

```
eb init myapp --platform node.js-16
```

Answer (score 0):

open the config file in the elasticbeanstalk directory and put the version you

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Use the [-p parameter](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb3-init.html)

```
eb init -p "node.js 8.9.3"
```

Or any other version that is [supported](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/concepts.platforms.html)

Comment: This will not work, unfortunately, for node.js, since Beanstalk doesn't distinguish between different versions of node.js. Your command would have worked for "PHP x.x", "java x", etc. If you list all the Platforms using "list-platform-versions" and filter out the Node.js platforms, you'll see proof of this.