# How to specify Node.js version for AWS CDK with Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-cdk

There's a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48880546/how-to-run-eb-init-specifying-node-js-version-8) already there for regular CloudFormation, but I'm struggling to find any documentation for CDK configuration.

The latest version available for a specific platform is automatically used when specifying the ARN `arn:aws:elasticbeanstalk:eu-central-1::platform/Node.js running on 64bit Amazon Linux/4.10.2`, but I want to be able to specify the exact version `10.15.0`, available in the UI and via CloudFormation as linked.

The only references to CDK usage for Elastic Beanstalk are the [API docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/typescript/api/aws-elasticbeanstalk.html) and [this example](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-cdk-examples/tree/master/typescript/elasticbeanstalk/elasticbeanstalk-environment), but the docs don't mention the Node.js version and the example is for a stack with Java 8 (that also doesn't specify the exact Java version).

Comment: Perhaps the intention is to use the `solutionStackName` approach rather than the `platformArn` as it takes options - in your case - for specific Node version? See: (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-beanstalk-environment.html#cfn-beanstalk-environment-solutionstackname) … and … (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/platforms/platforms-supported.html#platforms-supported.nodejs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `solutionStackName` property to specify stack name and `optionSettings` for specifying Node version, for example:

```
const options: ebs.CfnEnvironment.OptionSettingProperty[] = [{
  namespace: 'aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:nodejs',
  optionName: 'NodeVersion',
  value: '10.15.0'
}];

const webAppEnv = new ebs.CfnEnvironment(this, 'nodeAppEnv', {
  applicationName: myNodeApp.ref,
  solutionStackName: '64bit Amazon Linux 2018.03 v4.8.2 running Node.js',
  optionSettings: options
});
```